# How to set the size of the placemark?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps

I make yandex map with placemark. For placemark i use follow preset:

> 'islands#blueHomeIcon'

I need set size for placemark icon:

> 268px x 268px

Please help me.

My try:

```
let map;
let latitude = 55.8005930;
let longitude = 49.2119510;
let zoom = 16;
let controls = ['fullscreenControl', 'rulerControl'];


ymaps.ready().then(() => {
  map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [latitude, longitude],
    zoom: zoom,
    controls: controls
  });

  setMarker([latitude, longitude]);
});

function setMarker(coords) {
  const marker = new ymaps.Placemark(coords, {}, {
    preset: 'islands#blueHomeIcon',
    iconImageSize: [268, 268]
  });

  map.geoObjects.add(marker);
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zlodiak/dk2wj1p6/2/)

UPD: i need use standart placemark icon (not custom image)

Answer (score 2):

To use `iconImageSize` property it seems you have to use layout `default#image` and provide your image.

```
myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {
        hintContent: 'A custom placemark icon',
        balloonContent: 'This is a pretty placemark'
    }, {
        /**
         * Options.
         * You must specify this type of layout.
         */
        iconLayout: 'default#image',
        // Custom image for the placemark icon.
        iconImageHref: 'images/myIcon.gif',
        // The size of the placemark.
        iconImageSize: [30, 42],
        /**
         * The offset of the upper left corner of the icon relative
         * to its "tail" (the anchor point).
         */
        iconImageOffset: [-5, -38]
    }),
```

https://tech.yandex.com/maps/jsbox/2.1/icon_customImage

Comment: Thanks! But i need use placemark icon (not custom image)

Comment: I think you can't customize the icon size if you're not providing its image.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's true.